# Webpack and wordpress only to manage sass

Tags: javascript, wordpress, webpack, sass

I'm trying to use webpack only to parse my scss files to css in development environement and I was wondering if there were a way to avoid .js file generation ?

I'm new to webpack and I don't know if this is a way of using webpack that is desirable.

Comment: Why use webpack instead of a scss complier?  Seems to be way overkill.

Comment: If you only need sass, you can use sass commands (`sass sass/style.scss:style.css`) instead of webpack

Comment: I thought that webpack could easily scale from micro managing little task like that to more complexe assets compiling process.
Thanks Maxwell but I already know how to compile via the sass command.

Comment: For example, if I want to use compass and minify my css code after or apply operation on my image with some webpack compatible script ? Is it justified to use webpack like that ?